# How to eliminate the need of JIT when target platform is pre-determined?

Tags: java, .net, operating-system, platform-independent

It is great that using Intermediate Language (.Net: MSIL, Java: Bytecode) we can achieve platform independence. But when an application is supposed to run on a single platform only (e.g. Windows), in that case is there any simple way to specify that "I don't need JIT every time just give me the native code."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single platform (Windows) doesn't really mean single target. I'm currently running on Windows - and some binaries are x86, and some are x64. Even within the same processor family, different specific chips have different abilities that the JIT could take care of.

On .NET you *can* use [NGEN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf.aspx) - but personally I would see how much benefit there is before you actually use it in production. I believe the main benefit is in terms of start-up time rather than performance when actually executing. In fact, I believe there are some optimizations that the "normal" JIT can make which NGEN won't.

One point to note is that although the Hotspot JIT for Java is adaptive as Dolda2000 mentions, the .NET JIT is *currently* "once only" - it won't re-JIT code putting in more effort if it turns out to be very heavily used, or make assumptions around subclassing and then "undo" them later.

Answer (score 4):

I cannot speak for .Net, but there certainly are native Java compilers, such as GNU GCJ.

More importantly, however, are you really sure that you *want* to avoid JITing? A JIT compiler, operating as it is on knowledge of the global state of the code, can often make optimizations that static compilers cannot. For example, a JIT compiler can inline virtual methods when it knows that no subclass *currently* exists that overrides it (whereas a static compiler couldn't know if such a class would be (statically or dynamically) linked in later on). There are many other examples as well, but I don't think the scope of this answer is to list them. :)

Answer (score 1):

Another point:

Many current frameworks manipulate the bytecode during classloading. This means that the code on disk is not the code executed. Any Java Framework doing annotation based dependency injection will use this. JPA/Hibernate use this. AOP (Aspect Oriented Programming) usually use this, although the AOP frameworks *usually* also provide a way to manipulate the class files during the build.

Compiling the code upfront into native code would render these frameworks useless.